# Possible Buffer Overrun

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, buffer-overflow

I'm having an infuriating issue here where I'm crashing on `malloc`/`calloc`/`strdup` and I'm assuming currently that it's because of a buffer over run somewhere.

I'm finding this very difficult to find and I was wondering if any of you can offer me a hand. I'll post code snippets here, and link to full source.

**File reading and array operations:** (common.c)

**[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/79wE9hHN)**

```
char * S6_ReadFileBytes(const char* path)
    FILE * file;
    long length;
    char * bytes = NULL;
    file = fopen(path, "r");
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END)
    length = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, 0);
    bytes = (char*)calloc(1, (size_t)length + 1);
    fread(bytes, 1, (size_t)length, file);
    return bytes;

S6_Array * S6_ArrayNew(size_t count, size_t typeSize)
    S6_Array * a = (S6_Array*)malloc(sizeof(S6_Array));
    a->typeSize = typeSize;
    a->Length = count;

void * S6_ArrayGet(S6_Array * a, int idx)
    return &((char*)a->Data)[idx * a->typeSize];

void S6_ArraySet(S6_Array * a, int idx, void * val)
    memcpy(&((char*)a->Data)[idx * a->typeSize], val, a->typeSize);

void S6_ArrayGrow(S6_Array * a, int amount)
    void * data;
    data = realloc(a->Data, (a->Length + amount) * a->typeSize);
    a->Data = data;
    a->Length += amount;

void S6_ArrayPushBack(S6_Array * a, void* val)
    S6_ArrayGrow(a, 1);
    S6_ArraySet(a, a->Length - 1, val);
```

**CSV Reading:** (CSV.c)

**[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/5ecHxQ8m)**

```
void S6_CSV_PushRect(S6_Array ** rectangles, S6_Rectangle * rect)
    if( !*rectangles )
        *rectangles = S6_ArrayNew(1, sizeof(S6_Rectangle*));
        S6_ArraySet(*rectangles, 0, &rect);
    else
        S6_ArrayPushBack(*rectangles, &rect);

int S6_CSV_ReadRects(const char* file, S6_Array ** rectangles)
    char * bytes = S6_ReadFileBytes(file);
    char * line;
    char * nameIndex;
    size_t nameLength;
    S6_Rectangle * tempRect;

    line = strtok( bytes , "\n");
    while( line )
        nameIndex = strstr(line, ",");
        tempRect = (S6_Rectangle*)calloc(1, sizeof(S6_Rectangle));

        nameLength = (size_t)(nameIndex - line) + 1;
        strncpy(tempRect->name, line, nameLength-1);
        tempRect->name[nameLength-1] = '\0';

        sscanf(nameIndex, "%*[,]%d%*[,]%d%*[,]%d%*[,]%d", &tempRect->x, &tempRect->y, &tempRect->w, &tempRect->h)

        S6_CSV_PushRect(rectangles , tempRect);
        strtok(NULL, "\n");
    free(bytes);
```

**A function where I modify the array:** (BinPacker.c)

**[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/zMBxAgbe)**

```
int S6_BinPacker_Pack(S6_Array * rectangles, int binSize)
    // This sort appears to be working fine. View pastebin for test.
    qsort(rectangles->Data, rectangles->Length, sizeof(S6_Rectangle*), S6_BinPacker_CompareRects);
```

**CSV Writing [CRASH]
:** (CSV.c)

**[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/5ecHxQ8m)**

```
void S6_CSV_WriteRects(const char* file, S6_Array * rectangles)
    char * bytes = NULL;
    char buffer[128];
    S6_Rectangle * tempRect;
    size_t i;

    for( i = 0; i < rectangles->Length; ++i)
        tempRect = *(S6_Rectangle**)S6_ArrayGet(rectangles, i);
        memset(buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer));

        sprintf(buffer, 
            "%s,%d,%d,%d,%d\n",
            tempRect->name,
            temprect->x,
            temprect->y,
            temprect->w,
            temprect->h);
        if( bytes )
            bytes = strcat(bytes, _strdup(buffer));
        else
            bytes = _strdup(buffer);
```

So I'm crashing here on the `strcat(bytes, _strdup(buffer))` line. When I separate it out It's still the string duplication or any sort of allocation I've tried.

I get the following break dialog from visual studio:

```
Windows has triggered a breakpoint in myapp.exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in Slant6.Debug.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.
This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while Slant6.Debug.exe has focus.
The output window may have more diagnostic information.
```

And the break point it triggers is in tidtable.c on

```
PFLS_GETVALUE_FUNCTION flsGetValue = FLS_GETVALUE;
```

**SOLUTION**

strdup doesn't do any allocations, and even if it did I would be leaking like crazy. So instead of:

```
bytes = strcat(bytes, _strdup(buffer));
```

in CSV.c, I replaced it with some manual string concatenation that's easier for me to read (and remember).

```
size_t oldSize = strlen(bytes);
size_t bufferSize = strlen(buffer);
size_t newSize = oldSize + bufferSize ;

char * newMem = (char*)calloc(newSize + 1, 1);

memcpy(newMem, bytes, newSize);
memcpy(&newMem[oldSize], buffer, bufferSize);

free(bytes);
bytes = newMem;
```

**/SOLUTION**

Comment: Are you really using no braces, or is this an error typing into stackoverflow? This isn't python, you need those braces.

Comment: You need to free the memory returned by _strdup (i.e. can't just pass it as a parameter to another funciton like strcat).

Comment: There seem to be braces missing. Anyway, without having analysed the code in detail, I'm pretty sure that you should set `a->Data` in `S6_ArrayNew`, probably to a newly allocated block of either `count` or `count+1` bytes (it's not clear to me what `count` *exactly* means here, but I notice that in `S6_ReadFileBytes` you allocate an extra byte beyond the file size). Maybe this already solves your problem.

Comment: @Godwin That doesn't even make sense. How could I get a buffer over run no less build or run the application with invalid syntax. If you look at the pastebin you'll see the full code rather then the snipits I provided.

Comment: @Xoorath: because different compilers use different (and sometimes volatile) was of interpreting code, I'm not aware of one that lets you leave off braces around functions but you never know. I didn't check your links, but I'm glad this wasn't the case.

Comment: Wait a minute... Trying something... My code doesn't make sense at the strcat. strcat obviously can't just jumble together two allocations. You're right @crashmstr that I have to do the free, and there's a small amount of extra work needed to join the strings.

Comment: @celtshk Don't I need to add a null terminator to the file length? I thought it wouldn't have one. I'll investigate the array suggestion as well if suggestion doesn't solve it.

Comment: @Godwin Fair enough man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking that this line:

```
bytes = strcat(bytes, _strdup(buffer));
```

Does not do what you think it does.

You are making a copy of a string (`buffer`), and then concatenating that onto `bytes`. The duplicated string is never freed and 
`bytes` is only as big as the last `_strdup`, thus doing a strcat will overflow the buffer.

You need to allocate (or reallocate) `strlen(bytes) + strlen(buffer)`, etc. etc. for the `strcat`.

Comment: Yup, that's it! I'll post the solution at the end of my original post.